# Android ViewPagerIndicator with Webview

Tags: android, webview, tabs, viewpagerindicator

I want to create an app with `ViewPagerIndicator` consisting of `WebViews` under each heading. I can't get the logic of `ViewPagerIndiactor`, will someone provide me with a detailed explanation on using it?

[ViewPagerIndicator website](http://www.viewpagerindicator.com/)

Comment: so you mean the highlighted dots based on pages you are navigating.

Comment: code is available at http://viewpagerindicator.com/ have you tried to understand from there.tell us a specific point where you are not able to understand

Comment: as i mentioned in problem that i cant get logic how to use webviews in each tab

Comment: what is going wrong in case of viewpager is your wbview is inside the viewpager.